# Three.js BufferGeometry vs Geometry for particles

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

Some particle examples use `THREE.BufferGeometry` and others use a simply `THREE.Geometry`. 
Some lines about pros and cons of every method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`THREE.BufferGeometry` is slowly replacing `THREE.Geometry` as it is computationally more efficient.

The `THREE.BufferGeometry` API may still be undergoing changes, so you have to be prepared for that.

The `THREE.Geometry` API is easier to use, perhaps, but that may be because it is more familiar.

Currently they are both supported.

Which one you use is up to you.

three.js r.67

Comment: should new apps start with `THREE.BufferGeometry` by default ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga If you use `Geometry`, the renderer will create a `BufferGeometry` internally anyway. Use `BufferGeometry` if you can. three.js r.82