# Three.js - Questions about (the use of) THREE.BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, buffer-geometry

As I understood [using buffer geometries](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry) will increase performance and decrease memory usage because *it reduces the cost of passing all this data to the GPU*.

And as I understood [from @WestLangley his post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23611127/1697459) here:

> `THREE.BufferGeometry` is slowly replacing `THREE.Geometry` as it is computationally more efficient.

*I am currently using three.js - **r72**.* 
When I draw my geometries make meshes and add them to the scene I see that there are two properties inside my geomtries `__directGeometry` and `_bufferGeometry`.

Here in a `THREE.BoxGeometry`:

[image]

Here in a `THREE.Geometry`:

[image]

Here in a `THREE.ShapeGeometry`:

[image]

My questions:

1. What is a `THREE.DirectGeometry` and what does it do? (I cannot seem to find any documentation on this)
2. Is this `THREE.BufferGeometry` stored in `_bufferGeometry` already automatically used? If not, can I simply use it instead of my geometry to boost performance?
3. There are conversion methods: `THREE.BufferGeometry` has `toGeometry` and `THREE.Geometry` has `toBufferGeometry`. If I convert all my normal geometries to buffer geometries using this method, will it give me the same performance increase compared to drawing them as a `THREE.BufferGeometry` from the start?
4. How and when should I use `THREE.BufferGeometry`?
5. When will three.js stop supporting `THREE.Geometry` in favor of `THREE.BufferGeometry`?

---

***NOTE:*** I couldn't find detailed information on when and how to use buffer geometries or when it is going to be replacing `THREE.Geometry`. But if someone has a good source or reference please leave a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `__directGeometry` is an internal data structure used to transition between `THREE.Geometry` and `THREE.BufferGeometry`. Do not mess with it.
2. `THREE.BufferGeometry.toGeometry()` and `THREE.Geometry.toBufferGeometry()` are convenience methods. The first one is helpful if your model loads as `BufferGeometry` and you feel more comfortable manipulating `Geometry`. If you want answers regarding performance, you need to do a test. Buffer geometries definitely load faster.
3. There are many examples showing the use of `BufferGeometry`. It would be wise if you understood the difference between "indexed" and "non-indexed" `BufferGeometry`. `BufferGeometry` with the `index` attribute defined allows for the sharing of vertices. Non-Indexed `BufferGeometry` is what we call "triangle soup".
4. `THREE.Geometry` will remain for the foreseeable future.

three.js r.73

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you still elaborate a bit on this part: *If I convert all my normal geometries to buffer geometries using this method, will it give me the same performance increase compared to drawing them as a THREE.BufferGeometryfrom the start?* because I am still not sure if I should redraw my geometries as buffer geometries to get max performance...

Comment: One more... Is there a performance difference between indexed an not indexed buffer geometries?

Comment: (1) As I said in #3. above, if you want answers regarding performance, you need to do a test of your specific application. (2) The renderer converts your normal geometries to buffer geometry anyway, so there should be no reason for you to do the conversion manually. It might be a good learning experience, however. (3) Indexed and non-indexed `BufferGeometry` may, or may not, have _significant_ performance differences. It would depend on the geometry.